# Why use absolute instead of relative imports in a Python package?

Tags: python, numpy

I've recently created a Python package, and within it, used only relative imports to access functions stored in other methods.

Now, in Numpy, I see a lot of files that make heavy use of absolute imports, e.g. [this file](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/8f547f246b0c7463768adebafe0a57df9c03321b/numpy/lib/function_base.py). It has a lot of statements like `from numpy.core import overrides`.

I don't see a disadvantage in using relative imports. Why are they doing it like that, instead of `from ..core import overrides`? Doesn't the absolute import require numpy to be already installed?

Comment: My first thought would be they would initially have wanted to support versions of Python not supporting relative imports (and then they carried on like that), but seems [PEP 328](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/) was approved in 2004 and NumPy 1.0 released in 2006 so maybe not. It could be just a matter of style, or developers not being used to relative imports.

Comment: For me, it's because of PEP8 recommendation, followed by IDE like PyCharm for example, allowing with a simple shortcut to add every needed import with absolute path.

Comment: It's a stylistic choice, and because readability matters.

Answer (score 2):

[Absolute vs Relative Imports in Python](https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/)

#### Absolute Import

> Absolute imports are preferred because they are quite clear and straightforward. It is easy to tell exactly where the imported resource is, just by looking at the statement. Additionally, absolute imports remain valid even if the current location of the import statement changes. In fact, PEP 8 explicitly recommends absolute imports.
>
> Sometimes, however, absolute imports can get quite verbose, depending on the complexity of the directory structure.

#### Relative Import

> One clear advantage of relative imports is that they are quite succinct.
>
> Unfortunately, relative imports can be messy, particularly for shared
> projects where directory structure is likely to change. Relative
> imports are also not as readable as absolute ones, and it’s not easy
> to tell the location of the imported resources.

[PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/): [about Imports](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports)